# how to make finished django app a website

Tags: python, django

So I finished making a simple django app. All it is, is a website which has a /admin page, where someone can sign into and create posts which update to the site. Basically like a blog. I could've done it with WordPress but I prefer django a lot more. My last question is, how do I know host the django app as a website? I don't want a step by step guide, I know this site isn't meant for it but can someone give me a textbook or a link to something which shows how to do it? Because really I tried looking and couldn't find anything. The app isn't for me, it's for an organization and I don't know if their site is going to be .com, .net etc. And I don't know what they will be hosting the site on but I really don't want to end up having to redo everything with WordPress in order to just host the site.

Comment: *sigh* https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/

Answer (score 0):

You could host your app on Amazon EC2.  If you Google [Django + EC2](https://www.google.com/search?q=Django%20EC2), you will see lots of tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

#### you can host use OPENSHIFT.

Create an account at http://openshift.redhat.com/

Install the RHC client tools if you have not already done so:

```
sudo gem install rhc
```

Create a python-2.6 application

```
rhc app create -a django -t python-2.6
```

Add this upstream repo

```
cd django
git remote add upstream -m master git://github.com/openshift/django-example.git
git pull -s recursive -X theirs upstream master
```

Then push the repo upstream

```
git push
```

Here, the admin user name and password will be displayed, so pay
special attention.

That's it. You can now checkout your application at:

```
http://django-$yournamespace.rhcloud.com
```

#### now the difficult part

you want to edit the files in folder `django/wsgi/openshift`

mostly you want to edit the `settings.py` and copy your project folder to this folder.

now check it in localhost ie `python manage.py runserver`. if it worked successfully you can call `git push` that is it.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.heroku.com/‎ is awesome web-hosting with django support and totally simplified deployment process. Tutorial included.